# How do I center-align footers and headers in an RTF document viewed by Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: ms-word, rtf

I have an RTF file that I've written which has a single page with a header and a footer. I'm trying to get the header and footer be center-aligned. However, it seems like no matter what I do, the header and footer always appear to be left-aligned in Microsoft Word 2010. Other programs (such as Quick View Plus) seem to center-align the text just fine. Am I messing up the RTF here? Or is there an issue with Microsoft Word 2010? The contents of the RTF are as follows:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033
{\fonttbl{\f0\fmodern\fprq1\fcharset0 Courier New;}}
{\header
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20\qc
HEADER
}
{\footer
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20\qc
FOOTER
}
\margl200\margr200\margt200\margb200
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20\sl495
000001\par
      01    \line
      02    UNITED STATES DISTRICT COURT\line
      03    SOUTHERN DISTRICT OF NEW YORK\line
      04    DOCKET No. (DAB)\line
      05    --------------------------------------------x\line
      06    BLAH BLAH, et al,\line
      07                                 Plaintiffs,\line
      08        vs\line
      09    BLAH BLAH., et al,\line
      10                                 Defendants\line
      11    --------------------------------------------x\line
      12    \line
      13         EXAMINATION BEFORE TRIAL of BLAH BLAH\line
      14                   New York, New York\line
      15         Tuesday, December 14, 2004, 10:22 a.m.\line
      16    \line
      17    \line
      18    \line
      19    \line
      20    \line
      21    \line
      22    \line
      23    \line
      24    \line
      25    \line
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding \par after your header text.

```
{\header \pard \qc Centered Header \par}
```